# Sonata admin bundle : Accessing the child edit route from an embed admin class

Tags: symfony, routes, sonata-admin

I'm having some headaches trying to , i guess, remake the wheel.

In sonata admin bundle , i'm trying to make a logical navigation through all my admin entities.

Each entities are related in cascade like this : programEntity -> LevelEntity -> ExerciceEntity -> somethingEntity -> etc

From what i've read , sonata admin bundle handle ( hope this will change ) only one embed relation between a parent and a child admin class .

The fact is not very user friendly to be able to edit / list parent's children and go back to dashboard to edit / list parent 's grandchildren

I'm currently trying to make a custom route for editing a parend's child by removing the parent's path from the edit route :

```
http://localhost/domain/admin/acme/app/parent/4/child/3/edit
```

i would like to replace this url by direct one like this :

```
http://localhost/domain/admin/acme/app/child/3/edit
```

This way i would be able to access grand children from the parent 's selected child.

I tried to override generateObjectUrl and generateUrl from sonata adminClass without a success, i have also in mind to override template for each of my entities but it's not very poo oriented .

any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was able to find a way to resolve this :

1) override base_list_field in your own bundle ( copy the files in vendor\sonata-project\admin-bundle\Sonata\AdminBundle\Resources\views\CRUD\base_list_field.html.twig in your own bundle like acme/bundle/resources/views/CRUD )

2) modify the file to looks like this :

```
{#

This file is part of the Sonata package.

 (c) Thomas Rabaix <thomas.rabaix@sonata-project.org>

 For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
file that was distributed with this source code.

 #}

 <td class="sonata-ba-list-field sonata-ba-list-field-{{ field_description.type }}"     objectId="{{ admin.id(object) }}">
    {% if
        field_description.options.identifier is defined
    and field_description.options.route is defined
    and admin.isGranted(field_description.options.route.name == 'show' ? 'VIEW' : field_description.options.route.name|upper, object)
    and admin.hasRoute(field_description.options.route.name)
%}

<script type="text/javascript">
    var route = "{{ admin.generateObjectUrl(field_description.options.route.name, object, field_description.options.route.parameters) }}";
    var url = route.split(/(app)\//);
    var tabUrl = url[2].split ( "/" );
    alert ( 'test' ) ;

    var new_url = '';

    // case where adminclass is a child
    if ( tabUrl.length == 5 )
    {
        new_url = url[0] + url[1] + '/' + tabUrl[2] + '/' + tabUrl[3] + '/' +  tabUrl[4] ;
    }

    // case where adminclass is not a child
    if ( tabUrl.length == 3 )
    {
        new_url = "{{ admin.generateObjectUrl(field_description.options.route.name, object, field_description.options.route.parameters) }}";
    }

    document.write( {%raw%}"<a href='"{%endraw%} + new_url + {%raw%}"'>{%endraw%}{%- block field %}{{ value }}{% endblock -%}{%raw%}</a>"{%endraw%} );
 </script>
{% else %}
    {{ block('field') }}
{% endif %}
```

if the tabUrl ( whitch is a split of the url with '/' ) find 5 results , it means that we are in adminclass embedded , otherwise it's a normal admin class listing .

the code is not very clean and optimized but it works .

3) update your config.yml

```
sonata_admin:
title: Bonk
title_logo: public/img/logo-admin.png
security:
    handler: sonata.admin.security.handler.noop
templates:
    # default global templates
    layout:  SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig
    ajax:    SonataAdminBundle::ajax_layout.html.twig
    dashboard: SonataAdminBundle:Core:dashboard.html.twig

    # default actions templates, should extend a global templates
    list:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list.html.twig
    show:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show.html.twig
    edit:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:edit.html.twig

    ------>>>  base_list_field: AcmeMyBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
```

and

```
sonata_doctrine_orm_admin:
# default value is null, so doctrine uses the value defined in the configuration
entity_manager: '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager'

templates:
    form:
        - SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle:Form:form_admin_fields.html.twig
    filter:
    - SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle:Form:filter_admin_fields.html.twig
    types:
        list:
            array:      SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_array.html.twig
            boolean:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_boolean.html.twig
            date:       SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_date.html.twig
            time:       SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_time.html.twig
            datetime:   SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_datetime.html.twig
            text:       acmeMyBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
            trans:      SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_trans.html.twig
            string:     acmeMyBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
            smallint:   acmeMyBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
            bigint:     acmeMyBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
            integer:    acmeMyBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
            decimal:    acmeMyBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
            identifier: acmeMyBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
```

hope this will help  !